# ORA-01722 ERROR message : SUM DECODE SUBSTR

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to TOTAL `(tran_qty * PRICE)` for BUY and SELL
This is the results I want:

```
|CONTRACT| TRAN_QTY|PRICE
BUY         50    1.2
BUY         20    2.0
SELL        10    1.0
SELL        40    2.5
```

But when I ran the query below I got this error at line 1.

> error at line 1
>   ORA-01722: invalid num

What should I  do for this?

```
SELECT sum(decode(substr(O.tran_no,1,1), 'B', 'BUY')) BUY,
       sum(decode(substr(O.tran_no,1,1),'S', 'SELL')) SELL,
       O.TRAN_QTY,
       O.PRICE,
       o.client_no,
       c.client_name,
       sum(o.tran_qty*o.price)total,
       o.branch_code,
       r.descr,
       O.CURRENCY,
       O.STOCK_NO,
       O.CSTAMP 
from bos_m_ledger o,bos_m_para r,bos_m_client c,bos_cltype g 
WHERE r.para_type='BRANCH' AND 
       R.PARA_CODE = O.BRANCH_CODE and 
       o.client_no=c.client_no and 
       g.nbrk_rate=1 and 
       c.client_type=g.client_type and 
       o.tdr_code=c.tdr_code and 
       o.tran_type= 'CON' AND 
       C.CLIENT_TYPE='6' 
group by substr(o.tran_no,1,1),
       o.client_no,
       o.branch_code,
       r.descr,
       c.client_name,
       O.CURRENCY,
       O.STOCK_NO,
       O.CSTAMP,
       O.TRAN_QTY,
       O.PRICE 
ORDER BY O.BRANCH_CODE, O.CLIENT_NO'
```

Comment: google with error cod 'ORA-01722' you can find more valuable answers

Comment: Make sure you are passing a numeric value or not. If you want to know more about this error pls refer the following link. https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora01722.php

Comment: thanks, i'm new to this and still find the solution. tq

Comment: What is the result when you add strings 'BUY' + 'BUY'? In other words: if BUY and SELL are **column names**, then remove single quotes. If they are not, well, that SUM doesn't make any sense.

Comment: BUY and SALE is column. but in database its under column 'tran_no'. so i need to sum buy and sell so, in oracle report it will be 2 field. @Littlefoot

Comment: *CONTRACT*| *TRAN_QTY* | *PRICE*
BUY        |          50         |       1.2
BUY          |       20            |        2.0
SELL             |          10          |       1.0
SELL       |       40             |       2.5


i need to TOTAL(tran_qty * PRICE) for BUY and SELL
what should i do for this?

kindly help me.

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summing a string of 'BUY' or 'SELL' doesn't make any sense. I suspect you are trying to finagle a `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression` error. Also, as you are trying to get an aggregated total it doesn't make sense to include `TRAN_QTY` and `PRICE` in the projection and group by clause.

So probably what you need to do is something like this:

```
SELECT decode(substr(O.tran_no,1,1), 'B', 'BUY' ,'S', 'SELL') as contract,
       o.client_no,
       c.client_name,
       sum(o.tran_qty*o.price) as total,
       o.branch_code,
       r.descr,
       O.CURRENCY,
       O.STOCK_NO,
       O.CSTAMP 
from bos_m_ledger o,bos_m_para r,bos_m_client c,bos_cltype g 
WHERE r.para_type='BRANCH' AND 
       R.PARA_CODE = O.BRANCH_CODE and 
       o.client_no=c.client_no and 
       g.nbrk_rate=1 and 
       c.client_type=g.client_type and 
       o.tdr_code=c.tdr_code and 
       o.tran_type= 'CON' AND 
       C.CLIENT_TYPE='6' 
group by decode(substr(O.tran_no,1,1), 'B', 'BUY' ,'S', 'SELL'),
       o.client_no,
       o.branch_code,
       r.descr,
       c.client_name,
       O.CURRENCY,
       O.STOCK_NO,
       O.CSTAMP
ORDER BY O.BRANCH_CODE, O.CLIENT_NO;
```